# Keyboard hides input field in flutter

Tags: flutter

I've seen this question has been asked many times but none of the solutions is working for me. In the code below when clicking into the `bio` input field the keyboard overlaps this field. I tried with `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true`, with and without `SingleChildScrollView` but the behaviour dosen't change.

```
Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: ...
        body: SingleChildScrollView(child:
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 110, vertical: 16),
          child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 40),
                Text('Username'),
                TextFormField(

                  controller: userName,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
                Text('Screen name'),
                TextFormField(

                  controller: screenName,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
                Text('Bio'),
                TextFormField(

                  controller: bio,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
```

**Update:**
I've created an empty app on which it works fine. So the code seems to be correct. I compared `AndroidManifest.xml`. The lines are the same:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Has anyone an idea what could be different?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this code and it is working fine.

```
Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(child:
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 110, vertical: 16),
          child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 40),
                Text('Username'),
                TextFormField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
                Text('Screen name'),
                TextFormField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
                Text('Bio'),
                TextFormField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),]))));
```

If you still have problem please share some screenshot So it will be more helpful to understand.

Comment: Increase the height of the `SizedBox` so the bio input field is at the bottom of the screen. Now click on the input field. Now the keyoard shows and overlaps the input field. What I expect is the screen is resized and scrolling down so the input field stays visible.